# Unix/Solaris: Deleting a a directory is not possible because there are pseudo-files

Tags: file, unix, directory, solaris, delete-file

I'm currently compiling different PHP versions and want to delete some rubbish folders.

I got a folder called "php-5.4.7-src" which i want to delete but when I do

```
$ rm -Rf php-5.4.7-src
```

there always pops  up

```
rm: cannot remove directory php-5.4.7-src/ext/standard/tests/general_functions: File exists
rm: cannot remove directory php-5.4.7-src/ext/standard/tests: File exists
rm: cannot remove directory php-5.4.7-src/ext/standard: File exists
rm: cannot remove directory php-5.4.7-src/ext: File exists
rm: cannot remove directory php-5.4.7-src: File exists
```

So I did

```
$ find .
```

and

```
$ find . -type f
```

and there just pop up the folders above, no files exist.
I am also owner of all folders and I tried to delete them as root too.

How can I delete files which do not exist?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no process which is doing something to the directories? Re-creating files inside, holding something open?

Comment: it's on ufs filesystem.
@Jaka: Yes, im sure there is no process

Comment: have you tried 'unlink' command ?

Comment: Worked with 'unlink'. So this deletes its Inode?

Comment: it should. refer to unlink man page on your system.

Comment: Using unlink on directories on UFS filesystems generally causes corruption that fsck needs to clean up, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this does not answer your question but just a small matter of style that may save you headaches in the future. If you ever have to move your scripts to another flavour of UNIX there's a chance they will break. The traditional flag for doing a recursive delete is `-r`, not `-R`. Saves you having to push the shift key too :)

Now on to what may answer your question. I know you said you checked for running processes but that is the only way that an inode can be kept open, and only an open inode will keep a hierarchy from being removed. There are other processes such as `updated` that frequently run on systems that may have been crawling through your directories at the time. One thing you may try is to execute `sync` to ensure that all pending writes have been flushed.

*Something* is holding the directory open. You may also want to try `lsof +D php-5.4.7-src` to see exactly what.

Comment: Hi Kean, thanks for your answer and advice. 
Sadly `lsof +D php-5.4.7-src` did not do the job.